# PHP coders suggestions on alternative to WHERE NOT IN query

Tags: php, database, arrays, where-clause

I am trying to build a simple randomised voting system for a site, currently, and I believe wrongly, I have the following setup

as the user goes to the random voting section of the site, he is presented with a votable item that firstly, is an item that was last voted on the longest time agp, Secondly, isn't something the user voted for before and thirdly must be relevant to them based upon their list of relevant subjects. As a side note, if the user skips the vote, it can't show them the same thing again later in the list and all the single votes must be recorded to produce statistics.

Currently, the way I am doing this is by holding a serialized array against their account in the database containing a list of vote item Id numbers that they have previously voted for. 
I would like to say at this point that I don't condone this, and inserting a serialized array into the database was silly, and I regret my actions ;) .

Nevertheless, I couldn't figure out another way to do this. at this point, the array is built upon by users voting which adds to the list. but the query would become massive if I was to continue and someone had up to 100 things they could vote for. At this point I am using this query to get the next item in the list:

```
//$finarr is the received unserialized list of values from the database

$sql = "SELECT * FROM vote_item_headers WHERE Id NOT IN (".$finarr.") ORDER BY LastVoted DESC LIMIT 1"

//execute query and display results
```

I should also note that at this point, I haven't even bothered adding in the third requirement above because frankly, I didn't even know where to begin or anything when I had to make a query that needed to encompass all of the requirements above.

A bit more information you might find relevant:
I have some other tables which are explained below.

core_users = list of users and their interests
core_interests = a list of all interests
core_language = a list of the different possible languages that an item could fall into
vote_item_headers = a list of all the votable items with a reference in the interests and lang tables to define extra properties of the votable item. 
core_votes = the master list of people's votes

I am really sorry if this is too vague for you guys, all I really want is guidance in this instance when dealing with large amounts of information that needs to be combined to get a result.

Any suggestions welcome. I am happy to restructure the entire thing just to get it right.

Comment: Use a temporary table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM the_table_of_previously_selected_ids WHERE etc)
instead of a serialized results set

Comment: and can you link two where NOT IN statements? i.e NOT IN (SELECT) AND NOT IN (SELECT) or would it be Where not in OR type syntax. Cheers for your quick reply

Comment: you should only need one. I'll write it out

Comment: but yes you can use more. AND or OR depends on what logic you want. Can't see anything in the question that suggests you'd use another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`voted`

```
user_id   | Id
----------+------
    1     | 12
    1     | 14
    1     | 187
    2     | 23

SELECT * FROM vote_item_headers 
    WHERE Id NOT IN (
        SELECT Id FROM voted WHERE user_id=1234
    ) 
    ORDER BY LastVoted DESC LIMIT 1
```

but you also want relevant posts

`relevant_posts`

```
user_id   | Id
----------+------
    1     | 342
    1     | 253
    1     | 32
    2     | 53

SELECT vote_item_headers.* FROM vote_item_headers 
    # cut down the amount returned with relevant_posts table
    INNER JOIN relevant_posts ON (
        vote_item_headers.Id=relevant_posts.Id
        AND user_id=1234
    ) 
    WHERE vote_item_headers.Id NOT IN (
        SELECT Id FROM voted WHERE user_id=1234
    ) 
    ORDER BY LastVoted DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Awesome, that solves all of my problems. You're a serious dude. I should be able to get it all done with this. Cheers

Comment: It's cool, I have just re-structured to take this query into account, I am ready to test it now. Cheers again

Comment: Sorry, I have just built a load of this stuff into my site, and then went to create the temp table of votes. Apparently the host doesn't allow temp tables, do you know of any alternatives? Cheers.

Comment: so they decide what privileges you have for your own db?

Comment: Yeah, However, I am now discussing with them the relevance of this to my project and I think they are going to grant me privs. The problem is that it's shared hosting and they are picky about letting people consume ram, as they don't know what's going to be stored in there.